# How to display/render a 2D multiple image by image slider with ARCore in android studio

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, image-slider

I am new to android and there is my first augmented reality related project. I am trying **ar invitation card.** I have found a solution by stackoverflow like this : https://thomasgorisse.github.io/sceneform-android-sdk/ in (simple-augmented-images) but i didn't understand how to create **2d image slider** using image detection.